# Using macros in resource files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I would like to use #define'd strings in my .rc file. For example, say I have #include'd this .h file in my .rc file:

```
#if defined(RED_BUILD)
  #define CAPTION_TEXT "Red Window"
  #define PROMPT_TEXT "Red Prompt"
#else
  #define CAPTION_TEXT "Blue Window"
  #define PROMPT_TEXT "Blue Prompt"
#endif
```

In my .rc file, say I have the dialog box:

```
IDD_Dialog DIALOG 0, 0, 286, 258
STYLE WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "First " CAPTION_TEXT " Dialog"
BEGIN
  LTEXT "First " PROMPT_TEXT, -1, 4, 80, 120, 8
  LTEXT "Second " PROMPT_TEXT, -1, 4, 90, 120, 8
END
```

However the resource compiler does not like this, giving a "BEGIN expected in dialog". Is there any way I can coax the precompiler to handle this?

My current workaround is **#if defined(RED_BUILD)** in my .rc file, which works, but is not ideal, as I have hundreds of prompts that I need to change.

Comment: No, the windows framework that I used was written in-house.

Comment: Have you tried using multiple string tables and hacking the localization feature to load different dlls that contain different strings ?

Comment: This product was never localized and there are a lot of dialogs, I was hoping I could find something a bit easier than moving all those strings over to a localization table.

Comment: Isn't this what the string table is for in the resource file?

Comment: This is maintenance on a 10 year old product, so the poor planning was done some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to maintain different resource files and and compile them instead of handling everything inside one big "ifdef`d" resource file.